# syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83: theme_tests.html(A DOCTYPE is not allowed in content)

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, syntaxhighlighter

I am getting an error on **theme_tests.html** page provided with **syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83**, which I wasn't getting earlier.
The error is **A DOCTYPE is not allowed in content** at `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` inside first script tag `<script id="sample" type="text/plain">` tag.

Here is the page **theme_tests.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>SyntaxHighlighter Theme Tests</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="output"></div>

<style>
body {
    background: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.test-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
}
</style>

<script id="sample" type="text/plain">
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>SyntaxHighlighter Theme Tests</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        &lt;script>
        /**
         * Looks for a child or parent node which has specified classname.
         * Equivalent to jQuery's $(container).find(".className")
         * @param {Element} target Target element.
         * @param {String} search Class name or node name to look for.
         * @param {Boolean} reverse If set to true, will go up the node tree instead of down.
         * @return {Element} Returns found child or parent element on null.
         */
        function findElement(target, search, reverse /* optional */)
        {
            if (target == null)
                return null;

            var nodes           = reverse != true ? target.childNodes : [ target.parentNode ],
                propertyToFind  = { '#' : 'id', '.' : 'className' }[search.substr(0, 1)] || 'nodeName',
                expectedValue,
                found
                ;

            // main return of the found node
            if ((target[propertyToFind] || '').indexOf(expectedValue) != -1)
                return target;

            return found;
        };
        &lt;/script>

    </body>
    </html>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var themes = [
        ['#fff', 'Default'],
        ['#000', 'Django'],
        ['#fff', 'Eclipse'],
        ['#000', 'Emacs'],
        ['#000', 'FadeToGrey'],
        ['#000', 'MDUltra'],
        ['#000', 'Midnight'],
        ['#000', 'RDark']
    ];

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var sample = $('#sample').text().replace(/</g, '&lt;');

    $.each(themes, function(index)
    {
        var $iframe = $('<iframe class="test-wrap" src="about:blank" />'),
            background = this[0],
            themeName = this[1]
            ;

        $('#output')
            .append(''
                + '<h1>'
                    + '<a href="#theme' + (index + 1) + '">next</a> '
                    + '<a name="theme' + index + '">'
                        + themeName
                    + '</a>'
                + '</h1>'
            )
            .append($iframe)
            ;

        $iframe.ready(function()
        {
            var doc = $iframe[0].contentDocument;
            $iframe.css('background', background);

            doc.write(''
                + '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/sh/scripts/XRegExp.js"></scr' + 'ipt>'
                + '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/sh/scripts/shCore.js"></scr' + 'ipt>'
                + '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/sh/scripts/shBrushXml.js"></scr' + 'ipt>'
                + '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/sh/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></scr' + 'ipt>'
                + '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/sh/styles/shCore' + themeName + '.css"/>'
                + '<pre type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: js; html-script: true; highlight: [5, 20]" title="This is SyntaxHighlighter theme ' + themeName + ' in action!">'
                    + sample
                + '</pre>'
                + '<pre type="syntaxhighlighter" class="brush: js; html-script: true; collapse: true">'
                    + sample
                + '</pre>'
                + '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">'
                    + 'SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();'
                + '</scr' + 'ipt>'
                );
            doc.close();
        });
    });

    $('#output a[name]:first').attr('name', 'top');
    $('#output a[href]:last').attr('href', '#top').html('top');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The web page page I have in my java web application is rendering alright in chrome but not on firefox 4.
I remember the same page in my application used to work alright on both browsers before.

Only changed I have done to my system ever since I saw my application rendering the same page properly are:

1. I added jquerywtp1.10 plugin to my eclipse 3.5 IDE.
2. Updated firefox to firefox 4 version.

Could someone help me understand what should I do to get the same web page properly displayed on mozilla firefox 4 as well?

This is where I am getting the error, on line number 29: http://programatori.evonet.ro/images/1308360109285/doctype.jpg

theme_tests.html is could be found at: https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/src/a8771a7fc81d/tests/theme_tests.html

Could someone enlighten me for how to do away with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the document to be a XHTML strict document. However, the document structure violates the doctype rules. Nesting another `<!DOCTYPE` in the document is illegal. Also putting the JS code with unescaped XML entities in a XHTML strict document is illegal. Learn about doctypes at http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype and validate your document against the http://validator.w3.org.

Your first step is to wrap that nested XHTML document in a `<![CDATA[` block and move all that JS out into its own `.js` file. Also, having the `<style>` without `type` attribute outside the `<head>` is illegal.

This problem has nothing to do with JSP. It's just basic (X)HTML knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem I was getting in my application was because of something very silly I was doing. It had nothing to do with DOCTYPE. All I knew about DOCTYPE was that in case of HTML it tells you the kind of HTML to be used in the document and for XML it tells you about the constraints on the structure of an XML. Many thanks for reply :).